# how to get server ping on fabricmc

Tags: minecraft-fabric

I am trying to make ping overlay mod on fabricmc 1.19.2, and I can't find any references related with that. I tried `MinecraftClient.getInstance().player.networkHandler.getPlayerListEntry(MinecraftClient.getInstance().player.getUuid()).getLatency();`but it gave me nullPointerExeption that says this.client is null